# How to delete millions of records from table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.4, performance, postgresql-performance

I am using postgree 9.4 database and I have a table `snapshots` with 700+ million rows and I want to delete about 9 million rows. I have tried different queries to delete records, but no success.

Query to delete all records for a specific camera:

```
DELETE FROM snapshots where camera_id = 1248
```

Another query to delete recodes between `snapshot_id`:

```
DELETE from snapshots where snapshot_id >= '1248_201511010000000' and <= '1248_20151130235959000'
```

Suggest me what will be the fastest way of deleting records from 700+ millions records.

Comment: Are there any foreign keys pointing at the `snapshots` table? Can you post an EXPLAIN ANALYZE of a slow DELETE?

Comment: "no success" is neither a valid error message nor a useful description of the problem. Start by providing relevant details for your performance question as advised here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: There is no foreign key on table. It take too much time to executing query and at the end it gave message connection timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Other than breaking the operation into chunks, I don't think there's a silver bullet method. [This answer may come in handy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290900/best-way-to-delete-millions-of-rows-by-id)

Comment: My answer you refer to is only partly applicable since, in this case, only a small percentage of the whole table is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [`pg_repack`](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) to keep the table clustered by `camera_id`, or `snapshot_id` whichever one is responsible is more problematic. This will make the marking of the rows as dead a much faster operation. It's probably better to use `snapshot_id` **especially** if that is chronological, and you're not inserting old snapshots.

On the other operation, you can use an index.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it is faster to create a new table and insert only the records you would like to keep.

Comment: This is unlikely to be faster when keeping ~691 million of ~700 million rows.

Comment: It is true but maybe it will be easier to monitor the progress of insert